# FindFirstFileW wildcard match

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Consider a standalone example wherein I query for all the names in the directory with a wild card:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>

void add_file(const std::string &path)
{
    std::ofstream  ofs(path,std::ofstream::out);
    ofs.close();
}

void foo(const std::wstring& szDir)
{
    std::cout << "f1 : FindFirstFileW\n";
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW ffd;
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    hFind = FindFirstFileW(szDir.c_str(), &ffd);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind) 
    {
        std::cout << "Error in FindFirstFileW : " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return;
    } 

    // List all the files in the directory with some info about them.

    do
    {
        std::wcout <<"Long file name " << "  " <<  ffd.cFileName << std::endl;
        std::wcout <<"Short file name " << "  " <<  ffd.cAlternateFileName << std::endl;
    }
    while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

    FindClose(hFind);
}

int main()
{
    const char  odd_filename[] = {static_cast<char>(0xC4U), '.', 't', 'x', 't', 0};

    add_file("C:\\mydir1\\777.Txt");
    add_file(std::string("C:\\mydir1\\") + std::string(odd_filename));

    foo(L"C:\\mydir1\\7*");

    return 0;
}
```

This gives me output as below

```
f1 : FindFirstFileW
Long file name   777.Txt
Short file name
Long file name   ─.txt
Short file name   7F7E~1.TXT
```

Why does `FindFirstFileW` give back the second file name `Ä.txt` as a match ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wildcard match is applied to both long and short file names. The second file has a short name of `7F7E~1.TXT` and so matches `7*`.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) covers this like so:

> The following list identifies some other search characteristics:
>
> - The search is performed strictly on the name of the file, not on any attributes such as a date or a file type (for other options, see
>     `FindFirstFileEx`).
> - The search includes the long and short file names.
> - An attempt to open a search with a trailing backslash always fails.
> - Passing an invalid string, **NULL**, or empty string for the *lpFileName* parameter is not a valid use of this function. Results in this case
>     are undefined.

The second bullet point is the pertinent one.

Comment: Other than wasted space and time in directories and in getting a directory listing, this problem is another reason that I always disable legacy short names in NTFS. ReFS doesn't even support them. Code that relies on their existence is obsolete.

Comment: Raymond Chen also covered this on his blog: [Why does FindFirstFile find short names?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050720-16/?p=34883)

Comment: really need never use `FindFirstFile` but how minimum `FindFirstFileEx` with `FindExInfoBasic`